# Jquery:Remove DOM element after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am having trouble trying to remove an element after an ajax success..

here is my ajax code:

```
verifyRequest.denyUser = function(requestId,element){
    $.ajax({
        url: loaderURL+'idverified/denyRequest',
        dataType:"json",
        type:"post",
        data:{
            id:requestId,   
        },
        success: function(data){
            element.remove();
        }   
    }); 
}
```

And listening to this event:

```
$("#requestUsers ul li .remove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-value"),
        element = $(this).parent('li');

        verifyRequest.denyUser(id,element);     
});
```

The problem is this - The ajax is working fine however when it comes to the "success:" part
it does not remove the element.

I tried this code and it worked however this does not suit my needs :

```
$("#requestUsers ul li .remove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-value"),
        element = $(this).parent('li');

        verifyRequest.denyUser(id,element);
            element.remove();//and it did worked
});
```

can somebody explain why is this happening?Thanks

Comment: are you sure success callback is fired?

Comment: yes pretty sure.. return 200OK on console

Comment: Are you sure your "success" handler really gets called? Can you add console.log or a breakpoint there to verify?

Comment: Are you sure that element is a jQuery object.
If not you should do `$(element).remove();`

Comment: Try to `console.log(element);`
I think it is undefined, or not jQuery object.

Comment: @vekah `element = $(this).parent('li');` so it should be a jq object

Comment: Not if parent('li') returns anything...

Comment: I think Success is not being fired I tried alerting on success handler and did not fired

Comment: @vekah it is still an empty jq object ;) But anyway OP said it works when directly setted in click handler

Comment: @NEWBIE so your server doesn't return valid JSON

Comment: what could be the reason for this?

Comment: How are you generating JSON ?

Comment: @NEWBIE many reasons, maybe you should look at your server script...

Comment: I see the error now I am not returning a JSON.. what I did is just return a json value.. thnx

Comment: PLease consider updating the question with the correct answer or alternatively, add an answer yourself and accept it. It is listed as solved, but the solution is very hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
The problem is actually on server side .. If you are depending on success event your server side must always return a json.. even if its empty or what ever you prefer. Because success will be triggered only if

```
<?php  
 if(isset($_POST['yourData']) && !empty($_POST['yourData'])){
   if(//evaluate further){
     // This will trigger success
     echo json_encode(array());
   }else{
     throw new HttpException(403,'Unauthorized request');
   }
 }else{
  throw new HttpException(404,'Not Found')
 }
?>
```

This way success will be triggered if your evaluation returns true..

Answer (score 4):

store the reference and then remove it.this way:

```
verifyRequest.denyUser = function(requestId,element){
var t = $(element);
$.ajax({
    url: loaderURL+'idverified/denyRequest',
    dataType:"json",
    type:"post",
    data:{
        id:requestId,   
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(t).remove();
    }   
}); 
}
```

Comment: I think that on your success function you should do `t.remove();` and not `$(t).remove();` because you defined `t=$(element)`, and so it is already a jQuery object.

Comment: any error in console.Try giving alert on success function.

Comment: @vekah: $(element) will return jquery object. and yes you would need $(t) to access it.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar no, vekah is correct, no need to wrap it twice